# combine few DM scripts together to a gtk file

Tags: dm-script

I would like to combine few DM scripts together to a gtk file, is there any available  good script or tools for this function?  Could you share the link or resource to me? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, there are no tools other than the script-command which adds a script to a package (or creates it). Of course you can build a "management" script around it, and there is a tutorial with some examples on the FELMI database [here](http://portal.tugraz.at/portal/page/portal/felmi/DM-Script/Tutorials).

Comment: @together: Given the info that you posted with your previous question about bundling scripts into packages, it sounds like your already have a script that creates a package file but that you just need some help debugging it.  Please feel free to contact me directly for such help via the contact info given on my stackoverflow profile page.